# How do I get C++ programs to link with gcc's stack protector feature on AIX?

Tags: gcc, aix

I'm a bit of an AIX newbie. I'm trying to compile a program using gcc's stack protector feature. I installed gcc on server using pware's GCC package and I can compile a sample program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("hello world\n");

  return 0;
}
```

When I turn on stack-protector though, I get:
g++ -fstack-protector-all main.cpp
collect2: library libssp_nonshared not found

I've been hunting on google for a solution to this and it seems like my libc needs to have some stuff built into that mine doesn't. Is there a package out there that includes a libc with the stack protection builtin?

g++ -v returns

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0
Configured with: ../stage/gcc-4.2.4/configure --disable-shared --enable-threads=posix --prefix=/opt/pware --with-long-double-128 --with-mpfr=/opt/pware --with-gmp=/opt/pware
Thread model: aix
gcc version 4.2.4
```

I can not find libssp_nonshared.a on the system -- is there an additional package I need to install or should it have come with the gcc package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `libc`: your `GCC` installation is missing `libssp_nonshared.a` library.

What does your `"gcc --version"` say? It may have been configured with `--disable-libssp` option (in which case you can't use the stack protection instrumentation).

Update:
I just looked in `gcc-4.3.0/configure`:

```
 powerpc-*-aix*)
    noconfigdirs="$noconfigdirs gprof target-libgloss target-libssp ${libgcj}"
    ;;
```

I am about 99% sure this means that libssp (and therefore `-fstack-protector`) is not available for your platform. Sorry :-(